# Android just load default layout

Tags: android, layout, default

I started programming Android-Apps a few weeks ago. First, many thanks to all the members of this forum. Numerous posts helped me solving my problems with my app. But now, I have a problem I cannot handle and I dont find an answer.

So, what is the problem:

In my app I want to display a kind of table. On my main testing device everything fits good. But when i tried the app on an AVD with a smaller screen i realized, that the text size (in dp) is to big and the system creates a second row to display all the letters. Therefore, I decided to create an own layout for the four different classes of screen sizes with four different text sizes.

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch and many other posts on the internet the system choose the right layout automatically.

But I assert, that it doesnt. The system always load the default layout. I cannot understand why. When I delete the default order, it always load the small layout, even on my Galaxy Note 2. And on the AVD with the smallest screen, the app is closed with an error while starting. However, the normal layout runs on the smallest screen...

I even tried this to support the layout, but no success:
`<supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>`

Every xml-file has the same name. And th folders are named 'layout', 'layout-small', 'layout-large' and 'layout-xlarge'.

Can anyone help me? I guess, I just missed a little trick...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want 'layout', 'layout-small', 'layout-large' and 'layout-xlarge'.  While those do exist, they're sort of generic, and the behavior isn't as clearly defined.  See this table:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You are using size, not density.  Try these instead:`

```
ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
```

The resulting folders are `layout`, `layout-ldpi`, `layout-hdpi`, etc.  This is how I've always done it and it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not as perfect as I thought...
If I imagine a screen1 with a resolution of 480x800 with a density of 160dpi and a screen2 with a resolution of 480x800 with a density of 240dpi, the text size on screen1 will be smaller, altough the screen is bigger...
But what i need is, that the text size growth with the screen size. So, i thought, I would achieve this with a seperation into small, normal, large and xlarge layout.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more about density than size. Why don't you try instead of separating by size, to use ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but see my comment on DShaw's answer please.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think this is the best solution...

http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Scaling_Android_Apps_White_Paper.pdf